# How is the first premise true if variable $B$ is true?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Hi this is my second time on here so I am not quite able with the tools yet but I will try and do my best. I am currently studying [*How to Prove It*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=sXt-ROLLNHcC&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=let+the+statement+b+butler+is+innocent&source=bl&ots=BpIsqa3i73&sig=4s6CsG2mSReFGtrhTkl-nMwjYjo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJk6-AmrrLAhVEmYMKHYBgAVEQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=let%20the%20statement%20b%20butler%20is%20innocent&f=false) by Daniel J. Velleman page [19]

On page 19 number 2 the author assigns statement for 3 variables: $A,C$ and $L$.
$B$ is for the statement the butler is innocent, $C$ for the statement the cook is innocent and $L$ for the statement the butler is lying. He then goes on to create $2$ premises and then a conclusion. He then constructs a truth table for the premises and the conclusion. What I don't understand is how can the premise be truth in the fifth line. The $B$ in the fifth line is true which means the butler is innocent which contradicts the first premise which is both the butler and the cook are innocent.

Sorry if the question is not super clear. Please let me know how I can better my questions for next time and thanks in advance.

\begin{array}{r} 
\neg( B\land C)\\(L \lor C)\\\hline
\therefore \;\;L\,\lor \neg B\end{array}

Comment: Hey probablyme thank you for the help. Actually if you don't mind can you explain how you inserted a link into how to prove it. Also can you explain why my code wasn't good or at least why you decide to make it with being array. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for responding Mauro but I know that. What i am confused about is row 5 where B is true hence the statement the butler is innocent. So if that is the case how is the premise ¬(B∧C) also true since this premise says that both of them are not innocent.

Comment: $\lnot (B \land C)$ is true exactly when at least one of $B$ or $C$ is false.

Comment: Thanks for replaying justin. When you ¬(B∧C)¬(B∧C)  is true exactly when at least one of BB or CC is false this is because of Demorgans law right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the fifth line, where $B$ is T and $C$ is F, we have that $(B∧C)$ is $F$ and thus $¬(B∧C)$ is T.

But $L$ is F in this line; thus, $(L∨C)$ is F and we have to "discard" it.

As said in the text, the rows where the two premises:

> $\lnot (B \land C)$ and $(L \lor C)$

are both true are lines 2, 3, 4 and 6 of the truth table.

In these lines, the truth value of the conclusion is T; thus, the argument is valid.

Comment: I understand that but i was just looking at the other line to follow the reasoning behind the T or F and in line 5 we see that the premise if True even though the variable B is true. I know that i just need to look at the lines where both premises and conclusion are true to get the valid argument but that's not whats confusing me. Like i said its the fact that B is true hence the statement the butler is innocent. So if that is the case how is the premise ¬(B∧C) also true since this premise says that both of them are not innocent

Comment: Thats what i can't understand. How can ¬(B∧C) be T. Correct me if i am wrong please but doesnt this mean that both the cook and the butler are not innocent.

Comment: @samuel $\neg(B\wedge C) \equiv (\neg B)\vee (\neg C)$ via DeMorgan's Laws.  Evaluating your specific case from inside out you have $\neg(T\wedge F) \equiv \neg(F)\equiv T$.  "It is not the case that the cook and butler are innocent" is the same as saying "At least one of the cook or butler are not innocent" which is different than saying "Both of the cook and butler are not innocent"

Comment: can i also see it as ¬(B∧C)≡ ¬B∧¬C. Kind of a distributive law

Comment: @samuel if you send the negation inside, **it flips the $\vee$ to a $\wedge$ or vice versa**.  [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Comment: Oh i see so like you said its then either one of them. So even if the butler is innocent the cook isn't and since this is at least one that means that we can say that the premise as whole is true.